# Changing the name of the generated war file from command line with maven

Tags: maven

According to the [maven war plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) I should be able to set the name of the generated war file with the parameter `warName`. Is it not possible to do this from the command line with `mvn -DwarName=mySpecificName package`? When I run maven like this the war file still gets the default name.

My webapp project is part of a multi module project and I only want to change the final name of the war file, not any other projects generated artifact.

I am using maven 3.0.4 and version 2.3 of the war plugin.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect by maven property.

1) Define a property via

```
       <properties>
           <my.warName>xxx</my.warName>
       </properties>
```

You can overwrite the default value by "-Dmy.warName=commandlineWarName"

2) Redefine the war name

```
       <build>
           <finalName>${my.warName}</finalName>
           <!-- ... -->
      </build>
```

Comment: can we pass "xxx" from application.properties?

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the code of the war plugin I realize that it is not possible to set the `warName` parameter from command line. I assumed that all parameters were possible to set from the command line. This assumption was incorrect.